# Scala Play form date validation

Tags: scala, validation, date, playframework, playframework-2.5

I'm using Scala Play 2.5.x and I'm trying to do some date validation. The user can search for items with this form, along with the option of a date range: `fromDate` and `toDate`.

```
val searchForm = Form(
mapping(
  "itemID" -> nonEmptyText,
  "fromDate" ->  optional(date),
  "toDate" -> optional(date),
  "type" -> optional(text),
  "itemClass" -> optional(text),
  "status" -> optional(text),
  "component" -> nonEmptyText
)(SearchModel.apply)(SearchModel.unapply) verifying("To Date must be greater than From Date", f => f.toDate > f.fromDate))
```

The format validation is already covered by Play, but the problem is that the `toDate` needs to be greater than the `fromDate`, and if one of the dates are entered, the other must also be entered.

How do I implement these conditions in the form? Should I be doing this validation somewhere else like in the `view`, `controller` or `case class`?

Comment: In a controller you can implement any validations, but that costs a request/response cycle. For this particular case when you need to enable "toDate" field in case if "fromDate" is entered I think you need to add a simple javascript validation in your view. That way you will not need to reload the page like in the case if you implement that check in a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement you validation needs, you can keep it in your form definition and add an other `verifying`:

```
val searchForm = Form(
mapping(
  "itemID" -> nonEmptyText,
  "fromDate" ->  optional(date),
  "toDate" -> optional(date),
  "type" -> optional(text),
  "itemClass" -> optional(text),
  "status" -> optional(text),
  "component" -> nonEmptyText
)(SearchModel.apply)(SearchModel.unapply)
  verifying("You must provide zero or both dates", f => f.toDate.isEmpty && f.fromDate.isEmpty || f.toDate.isDefined && f.fromDate.isDefined)
  verifying("To Date must be greater than From Date", f => if (f.toDate.isDefined && f.fromDate.isDefined) f.toDate.get > f.fromDate.get else true)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the validation on forms using **.verifying**

```
    val searchForm = Form(
    mapping(
   "itemID" -> nonEmptyText,
   "fromDate" ->  optional(date).verifying("Invalid Date", date => true /* any condition or a function which checks the date condition*/),
   "toDate" -> optional(date),
   "type" -> optional(text),
   "itemClass" -> optional(text),
   "status" -> optional(text),
   "component" -> nonEmptyText
   )(SearchModel.apply)(SearchModel.unapply)
```

For refrence:- 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms#Defining-ad-hoc-constraints

I hope that's the thing you are asking for.